# prove a holomorphic function is polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, holomorphic-functions

Question :
Given a function f holomorphic in the unit disk D, and such that for every point z ∈ D, there exists an n ∈ N such that the nth derivative of f vanishes at z. Prove that f is a polynomial.

Intuitively I think the question is quite obvious, however , when I truly try to prove it formally , I am stuck.
Does anyone have any idea about this question? Truly grateful to any help!

Comment: hint: if $f^{(n)}$ is not identically zero then it has at most countably many zeros in D

Answer (score 2):

Let be $D_n = \{z\in D: f^{(n)}(z) = 0\}$. By hypothesis, $D = \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}D_n$. As $D$ is uncountable, Some $D_n$ is uncountable...

Comment: I changed $f_n$ to $f^{(n)}$ to make it clearer that it is the $n$th derivative. Hope you don't mind! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!!!

Comment: But I still have some confusion. Say there exists some integer N , s.t DN is uncountable , how can we claim that f coincides with a polynomial in DN?

Comment: Since if we can prove the claim , then by identity theorem , we can say f has to be a polynomial.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @fxy, the trick is: uncountable $\implies$ has an accumulation point in $D$.